# How to move directories which are created during last hour using windows batch scripts ?

Tags: windows, batch-file, scripting

I want to move the whole directory to one place to another predefined place based on below condition.

If **Folder created Date** < (**current time - 1hour**) then
Move the directory and it's content

Thanks,
Nir

Comment: Which version of Windows are you using? Are you OK with using powershell?

Comment: Take a look at the [forfiles](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753551.aspx) command.

Comment: @unclemeat forfiles can only do time differences in days and uses last modified time.